# How to retrieve request headers?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I am adding custom header in my request (sent from external app) to Joomla controller with a custom header added. How to retrieve the header in my controller?

I tried using below but it gives me null.

```
$token = $app->input->server->getString('Authorization');
```

Request captured shows the headers added.

```
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 25
D/OkHttp: Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MzYyMjQyOSwiZXhwIjoxNDc2MjE0NDI5fQ.l691z66kzWaEA6RP7schKk4-N6xvXzneAwvKQm-Cj8E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others facing similar issue:

It looks like Joomla or the server is simply ignoring the Authorization headers. Changing name of some other name will be a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain PHP to retrive request headers. No need to use Joomla objects. Use below code

```
$token =  getallheaders ();
print_r($token);
```

to retrive full request headers.

Comment: Your solution seems like a suitable solution for the question asked, but the quality of your post is definitely "low-value" on any/all Stack Exchange sites.  Thank you for endeavoring to contribute, but whenever you post a solution, you are expected provide more than just a code-only answer.  A "good" answer begins with a correct working solution, but it doesn't stop there.  Please do your best to educate not only the person asking the question but thousands of future researchers as well.  Please provide a sample output for context, a link to the php docs, and any other info you find relevant.

Comment: Please read [answer].  I will not be voting to Recommend Deletion because I feel your post adds otherwise missing value to the page.  Please take a moment to edit/improve your post.  Doing so will make your post and this site more valuable to researchers and it just might land you your first upvote.  Finally, please take the [tour] and earn your "Informed" badge.  This will help you to understand how you can best interact in this community.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use a different method than jinput.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$headers = $app->getHeaders();
```

See:

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JApplicationWeb.html#method_getHeaders

Comment: From API: `Method to get the array of response headers to be sent when the response is sent to the client.`. These are not headers sent from client to server, rather opposite.

Comment: Under what method are you sending it to the controller if not via http? Are you using a CLI?

Comment: I am using okHttp android client which uses http.